# Limit image by height AND width

Tags: html, image, css

I am having issues limiting my images by either width or height, whichever passes the limit.

Some images I upload are taller than 450px for example, while others are wider than 450px. How can I set them so both width and height won't go over 450px.

This is such a basic thing but I don't know how to do it, I appreciate any help!

EDIT: I was hoping this could be solved with css html, that's why I didn't mention language, but if it's a more complex solution, then I am using meteor.. so javascript and jquery.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? You haven't told us what programming language you're using to receive the uploaded content. Or are you just wanting to limit them with CSS?

Comment: I was hoping this could be solved with css html, that's why I didn't mention, but if it's a more complex solution, then I am using meteor.. so javascript and jquery. Thank you!

Comment: It'll be difficult to solve this with css. There's no real resizing taking place in css; you still have the same image content. Let's say for example you upload a 3840x2160 pixel image... if you resize that either in CSS, or on the server-side, to 450x450, it's going to be distorted. However, with CSS, you're going to be downloading a larger image every single time. This could put a strain on the server, or the user viewing the rendered page, if there are a lot of these images. Usually people create thumbnails for this purpose.

Comment: Hi Eduardo, thanks for your help. There were already two answers, the most voted one resolved this issue!

Comment: Yeah, so check the answer please. But please read my last post regarding the resizing of images. You don't want tons of huge files all over the page which aren't thumbnailed. This may or may not apply to you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `max-width` and `max-height` css properties (*and do not set `width`/`height` attributes on the `img` tag*)

```
img{
    max-width:450px;
    max-height:450px;
}
```

*keep in mind that this applies when displaying the images. If you want to limit the real width/height of the image to conserve space on the server you will have to look to uploading plugins with options for scaling down an image.*

Answer (score 1):

You could use the image `style` propertie:

```
<img style="max-width: 450px; max-height: 300px" src="image.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to "crop" the image like this:

```
<div style="max-height:450px; max-width:450px; overflow: hidden">
   <img src="myImage.png" />
</div>
```

This will crop from the top left corner, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score -1):

**Simple HTML**

`<img src="xyz.jpg" alt="Its You" height="200px" width="200px">`